# Samba share rejecting git pushes from Linux

Tags: ubuntu, git, samba

I've been having some issues pushing some old local repos on my linux machine to my samba share on a server on the local network.  On the remote machine I've created a folder for the repository, and initialized a bare git repo within with the command

```
git --bare init
```

To push, what I've done is logged into my share using Nautilus' Connect To Server Dialog, then copying the filepath to my bare repository to my local repository's remote path using

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=server-name,share=shared/path/to/repo
```

My pushes are always rejected with a message similar to:

```
fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To /path/to/repo/
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
```

Since it would seem the obvious problem is the unpacker error, i decided to run a `git repack` as well as a `git fsck` for good measure.  Re-pushed, no luck, same error.  I'd like to know if there's anything else I can do.  The server filesystem is indeed NTFS (it's a windows server)

Comment: have you confirmed that the share otherwise works  as expected for the users involved, including setting the owner/mode for new files on the remote end correctly and in a way that your GIT user can work with them after creation?

Comment: Yes, I have another repo that works fine on it.

Comment: Problem with filenames with non-ASCII characters? What happens if you try to just copy the git repo directory tree to the Samba share?

Comment: Copying with cp throws a bunch of 'function not implemented' warnings (probably due to file permissions on EXT4 vs NTFS) but ultimately works fine